# Rails polymorphic has_many/belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I have the following models:

```
User
- type

Account
- user_id

Aide
- user_id

Provider
- user_id
```

A User can have type ['account','aide','provider'], and it can have many of one type but it should not have multiple types associated with it.  So a User of type 'aide' has many aides but it should not have any accounts or providers.

Is there an established way to handle this type of association in Rails?  It's not really polymorphic in the traditional definition - it's more that the type of the parent defines the type of the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Account belongs to User
- Aide belongs to User
- Provider belongs to User
- User has many accounts
- User has many aides
- User has many providers

And then you can add a validation method in the User model class like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base # your User model
  validate :pick_a_name

  private

  def pick_a_name
    # check presence of associations that aren't of the users's type

    associations = %w{accounts aides providers} # use a constant

    associations.each do |a|
      if (a != self.type.pluralize) && send(a).present?
        # if such associations are present, add errors here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in the other classes:

```
class Account # your account model
  validate :pick_a_name

  private

  def pick_a_name
    if (user.type != 'account')
      # add errors here
    end
  end
end
```